# reuse of components it not works using angular 12

Tags: angular

I created my `services` and my `components`, I inject `component` `posts`, `services` and `sliders`,
acceuil component.

**acceuil.component.html**

```
<sliders [rowOfSliders]="rowSliders"></sliders>
<div class="container">
    <h2 class="mt-5">Nos Services</h2>
    <hr>
    <services [rowOfServices]="rowServices"></services>
    
    <h2 class="mt-5">Nos Actualites</h2>
    <hr>
    <posts [rowsOfPosts]="rowPosts"></posts> 
</div>
```

and i inject menu and `router-outlet` in `app.component.html`.

**app.component.html**

```
<menu></menu>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

everything works fine, in the menu there is blog, and I inject `posts` into `blog` components

**blog.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <h2 class="mt-5">Nos Posts</h2>
    <hr>
    <posts></posts>

</div>
```

when I click in the menu on blog it just displays Nos Posts, without posts.

**menu.component.html**

```
 <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link mr-3" routerLink="/blog">Blog</a>
</li>
```

**routes-routing.module.ts**

```
{path:"blog",component:BlogComponent},
```

I want to see where is the error

Comment: what is your expectation?. If you open f12 and see there's an element <posts>. You need to check posts component that it has data to render. I don't see code of post component